# I have a string with a number and a letter, is there a way to move the integer into a separate int variable?

Tags: java, string, variables, int

So I'm working on a school project and it includes a Combined Gas Law calculator where the user may input the temperature in °celsius (e.g. 1°C) and the code converts it to kelvin; if the user's input is in kelvin already, it does not do that and continues with the equation. So does anyone know how I can separate the two data types into two different variables in Java?

Comment: Do some research. You need to **1)** isolate the integer from the rest of the string (check out `String.split()`) and **2)** cast the string to an int (check out `Integer.parseInt(string)`)

Comment: Try using what @sleepToken proposes and edit your question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split over a specific string (degree character for example), store in a String array and parse the first element. Something like this:

```
String str = "47°C"
String[] strArray = str.split("°");
int number = Integer.parseInt(strArray[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations, you are working on something but not writing it's code. I can tell you a few tips about how to implement it's code.

1. You have a string that has some numbers in it, and also has unit. Try searching 'How to extract numbers from a string'. Now you have a number.
2. Find the unit in the string by looking the last character in the string.
3. If the condition is ok for your homework, calculate the new value.
4. Print the result.